# nextjs13 try to prevent to cache control using with 'no-store' and 'export const validate = 0' , but never work

Tags: caching, router, next.js13

I'm testing nextjs making small project, but i just find that server-component keep using cached data. So I have tried 'no-store' in fetch, 'export const validate = 0' whatever i can as document guides. But, still it keeps cache i think. Furthermore, while I'm testing i found that when i enter the server-component, at first time it seems keeping cache, but after around 30 seconds, it fetches updated data. (?)
is there any part that I'm missing here? please suggest any solution. lol

Here is my code block.

this is server component.

```
import Card from '@/app/common/card/Card';
import * as React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
export const validate = 0

export interface IPostListProps {
}

const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/post", {
        cache: "no-store",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    const posts = await result.json()
    return posts
}

export default async function PostList(props: IPostListProps) {
    const posts = await fetchPosts()

    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
                <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full'>
                    <Link href={"/post/write"} className='w-full sticky top-0 custom_button'>
                        + New
                    </Link>
                    <div className='flex flex-col gap-2 mt-3 w-full'>
                        {posts?.map((post: { _id: string, title: string, body: string, publishedDate: string }) => (

                            <Link key={post._id} href={"post/detail"}>
                                <Card post={post} />
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

this is client component (after request API, it just redirect to server-component)

```
'use client'
import QuillEditor from '@/app/common/editor/QuillEditor';
import * as React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export interface IPostWriteProps {
}

export default function PostWrite(props: IPostWriteProps) {

    const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('')
    const [body, setBody] = React.useState('')

    const router = useRouter()
    const inputHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value)
    }

    const writePost = async () => {
        const result = await fetch(`
            http://localhost:3000/api/post
        `, {
            method: 'POST',
            next: {
                revalidate: 0
            },
            headers: {
                "ContentType": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "123"
            },
            cache: "no-store",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: title,
                body: body
            })
        })
        console.log(result)
        if (result.status === 200) {
            **router.push('/post')**
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex flex-col justify-center gap-5'>
                <div className='w-full'>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name='title'
                        placeholder='Please Type Title.'
                        onChange={inputHandler}
                        className='placeholder:italic w-full text-xl outline-none md:text-2xl rounded-lg border border-gray-300 dark:bg-white py-3 pl-3' />
                </div>
                <div className=''>
                    <QuillEditor setBody={setBody} />
                </div>

                <div onClick={writePost} className='text-center border-2 rounded-lg px-3 py-3 font-bold cursor-pointer bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 hover:text-gray-400 hover:shadow-lg dark:hover:shadow-gray-600'>
                    Write
                </div>

                <Link href={"/post"}>
                    <div className='text-center border-2 rounded-lg px-3 py-3 font-bold cursor-pointer bg-gray-100 dark:bg-slate-900 hover:text-gray-400 hover:shadow-lg dark:hover:shadow-gray-600'>
                        List
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

I expected that after i type 'no-cache' in server component, the server gets new data per every request.